# Web.config in the root directory and in my subfolder. How to define the file in my subfolder as the main one for my application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, wwwroot

I have an application in my subfolder within wwwroot (Finance), which worked fine, but someone else installed another application not in a subfolder but in wwwrooot.
So there is a web.config in the wwwroot and in my subfolder.
When I run my application it no longer reads my file but rather the one in root. Regardless of whether the other application is installed incorrectly, how can I configure my application to read my file and not the root one?
Any configuration in IIS or in my web.config?

Currently exists:

- `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config`
- `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Finance\web.config`

I try:

```xml
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  .......
</location>
```

in different sections of my web.config but not working.
My web.config:

```xml
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
    .......
   </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    .......
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    .......
  </system.web>
  
  <system.webServer>
    .......
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web.extensions>
    .......
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Learn some Markdown syntax please, so that you don't need others to fix the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the configuration is correct, in the root's folder web.config  wraps the <system.web> element with the following element:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   <system.web>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

and leave all other settings elements unchanged.